# return parent property matching condition of child arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const obj = {
  main_id :1,
  inners: [{
    hasSomething: true
  }]
}
```

how to return obj's id when inners array has something is true?

`abc.inners.some(o => o.hasSomething) // but I want to return main_id`

I used some but it doesn't return obj's id.

Comment: can you show how you are defining `abc` ?

Comment: `some` is Javascript `Array.prototype.some()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `conditional operator` like

```js
const obj = {
  main_id :1,
  inners: [{
    hasSomething: false
  }]
}

const res = obj.inners.some(item => item.hasSomething) ? obj.main_id: undefined;
console.log(res)
```

Comment: hmm never thought of this